# Is there a faster way to concatenate two integers bit-wise?

Tags: c++, performance, bitwise-operators

For my C++ program I want to bit-wise concatenate two 32-bit unsigned integers into one 64-bit unsigned integer. Similar questions have been asked multiple times and the answers mostly looks similar to this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::uint32_t leftHalf = 1;
    std::uint32_t rightHalf = 2;
    
    std::uint64_t concatenated = ((std::uint64_t) leftHalf << 32) | secondHalf;
    
    std::cout << "left=" << leftHalf << " and right=" << rightHalf << " concatenated into " << concatenated << std::endl;
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XY7BDoIwDIbP7ikavMDBg2A8IHD2LczSDVwyNgLjpD777CBm4KFJ@39/2x@H4dQhen9UBvUsJFQ4OaGMa1iUlJ3cKHnfMEYEeq5MmrEXO5C1LGfSivzhQMvW3bluoYbz7R@Oqnv@aE50w68X4mgNcicNlSBLmu5wFo9XFRR5Bm@YJO2IoMVzaGcXHEmw10lot4sJcCPWKCuMqRa6C0GvLSyunUzz8koaoW/s4/0X)

Since I have to perform this concatenation a lot in my program, I need it to be very efficient. Using a cast, a shift and the bitwise |, makes it seem like another technique (e.g. using memcpy) could be quite faster.

### Is there a faster way to concatenate two integers than with a cast, a shift and a bitwise |?

For completeness, my *not*-compiling approach:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::uint32_t leftHalf = 1;
    std::uint32_t rightHalf = 2;
    
    std::uint64_t concatenated;

    std::uint32_t *halfIt = &concatenated;

    *halfIt = leftHalf;
    ++halfIt;
    *halfIt = rightHalf;
    
    std::cout << "left=" << leftHalf << " and right=" << rightHalf << " concatenated into " << concatenated << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222640/discussion-on-question-by-rayllum-is-there-a-faster-way-to-concatenate-two-integ).

Comment: Just make sure not falling into typical optimization traps. Prove first that this is a bottleneck. And if it is, first try and adjust your algorithms to avoid having to do this operation at all. It's extremely unlikely that this operation is your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combined information of the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222640/discussion-on-question-by-rayllum-is-there-a-faster-way-to-concatenate-two-integ) leads to the following answer to the original question:

## It depends. Also, a faster way most likely won't make a difference.

Depending on the surrounding code, the following techniques are possible:

- One can store the 32 bit parts as two elements in an array and then `memcpy` that array into a 64 bit integer. ([suggested by NathanOliver](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50630468#50630468))
- Depending on the way the 32-bit values are stored, one can use parallelization, e.g. with AVX commands ([suggested by sgorozco](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50630581#50630581))

### But it might make no difference

Other operations, such as a single fetch of data from memory/cache, take more run-time than *multiple* bit-wise operations ([pointed out by JulianH](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50630587#50630587)). Thus, with current CPU design, the bit-wise operations might run *during* a load operation and the next instruction waits for the time-consuming load operation to be finished.

Lastly, it is highly recommended to use a method (e.g. https://godbolt.org/, `gcc -S`, a profiler such as perf) to determine which parts of the code are taking the most time.

Answer (score 0):

If you find a valid way to copy a part (seen as bitset) of a value in a part (seen as bitset) of an other value, you can increase the speed additionally. But I guess this will be a little bit hacky.

By the way, in the following code the function `concat1` is one command shorter in the compiled code then `concat2`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::uint64_t concat1(const std::uint32_t& leftHalf, const std::uint32_t& rightHalf){
    std::uint64_t concatenated = leftHalf;
    concatenated <<= 32;
    concatenated |= rightHalf;
    
    return concatenated;
}

std::uint64_t concat2(const std::uint32_t& leftHalf, const std::uint32_t& rightHalf){
    std::uint64_t concatenated = (static_cast<std::uint64_t>(leftHalf) << 32) | rightHalf;
    
    return concatenated;
}

int main() {
    cout << concat1(1,2) <<std::endl;
    cout << concat2(1,2) <<std::endl;
}
```

You can see it in e.g. https://godbolt.org/. The function `concat1` needs one `mov` operation less then `concat2`. But the difference will be minor. I estimate ~5% of the runtime;

```
concat1(unsigned int const&, unsigned int const&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rsi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     eax, eax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        sal     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 32
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     eax, eax
        or      QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
concat2(unsigned int const&, unsigned int const&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rsi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     eax, eax
        sal     rax, 32
        mov     rdx, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     eax, eax
        or      rax, rdx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: Tried it in https://godbolt.org/ with `-O2` and `-O3`, for both GCC and CLANG, and the results for either compiler are all identical (with minor differences between GCC and CLANG - `sal` vs. `shl` and instruction order).

Comment: Even with the option -O2 and -O3, concat2 has one mov operation less.

Comment: @UweJ, They both give the same asm on Clang trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/4fWjf1. Passing by value instead of by reference saves one additional instruction / two pointer dereferences as well: https://godbolt.org/z/v3WjWq. GCC trunk gives very similar results.

Comment: @chris and Brendan. Thank you for your effort! I only tried one GCC compiler. The optimization capability of the compiler obviously has an higher impact then the micro-optimization I tried on the code. So my try is an example why micro-optimization should be avoided in many (maybe most) cases.